# How to embed VLC in zk's zul?

Tags: vlc, zk, zul

Using HTML, I can successfully embed VLC by object tag( please see the codes below).
Nevertheless, I couldn't  see any video being played when I embed the same html inside zul.

This one has succeeded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<object
  classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921' 
  codebase='http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab'
  id='vlc'
  name='vlc'
  class='vlcPlayer'
  events='True'>
    <param name='Src' value='rtsp://10.1.21.228/stream/live?ch=1_0' />
    <param name='ShowDisplay' value='True' />
    <param name='AutoLoop' value='False' />
    <param name='AutoPlay' value='True' />
   <embed id='vlcEmb'  type='application/x-google-vlc-plugin' version='VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2' autoplay='yes' loop='no' width='640' height='480'
     target='rtsp://10.1.21.228/stream/live?ch=1_0' ></embed>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

The following fails:

```
<?page title="new page title" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>


<html><![CDATA[
<object
classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921' 
codebase='http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab'
id='vlc'
name='vlc'
class='vlcPlayer'
events='True'>
  <param name='Src' value='rtsp://10.1.21.228/stream/live?ch=1_0' />
  <param name='ShowDisplay' value='True' />
  <param name='AutoLoop' value='False' />
  <param name='AutoPlay' value='True' />
 <embed id='vlcEmb'  type='application/x-google-vlc-plugin' version='VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2' autoplay='yes' loop='no' width='640' height='480'
   target='rtsp://10.1.21.228/stream/live?ch=1_0' ></embed>
</object>
]]></html>


</zk>
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: How does 'it fail'? Any error messages from your webapp server?

Comment: @Col , thank you. The server doesn't show any message.

Comment: I just tested your code and it 'potentially works' for me. (It didn't actually work in that both Chrome and Firefox complained with the following messages)
Chrome: This plug-in is not supported
Firefox: The connection to the site is untrustworthy, so the specified header was ignored.
This looks more like a browser issue rather than a ZK issue. Maybe the version you are using behaves differently; I tested with 8.0.5 EE.